# resource linking failed, error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-resources

When I integrate the Stripe library it creates linking resources
    problems due to the SDK version. While when I upgrade my SDK version
    from v7:27.1.1 to v7:28.0.0 and change my compile SDK version to 28
        the problem is resolved then it causes the problem in the Manifest file.
add this library for the SDK version but not solve the problem.

`build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    }}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goldtech.linkbreed"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 

    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

        //  for slider images
        implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2-appcompat'
        implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:11.2.0' // stripe  payment

        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'

        implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0' //  for stories
        implementation 'com.allattentionhere:autoplayvideos:0.2.0' // for video in recyclerview

        //  indicator //
        implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

        //////////////   exoplayer  //////////////////////

        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'


        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of mismatched `compileSdkVersion` and library version.
Change the `compileSdkVersion` to `28`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    ...
}
```